# Parsing MT4 config files

Tags: config, mql4, mt4

I'm trying to write an install script for an MT4 expert advisor. Part of the installation process includes adding an allowed WebRequest URL. I assume this is saved as a setting in `C:\Users\{User ID}\AppData\Roaming\MetaQuotes\Terminal\{Terminal ID}\config\experts.ini` as I can see the allowed URLs there, but I cannot parse this data as no editor I have can decode it. Is this file parsed using a proprietary encoding or is it encrypted in some way? Any help here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I could think of to address this issue was to create my own HTTP web request library, [here](https://github.com/xefino/mql-http), and use it to submit HTTP requests.

```
#include <mql-http/Request.mqh>
#include <mql5-json/Json.mqh>

int SendWebRequest(const object request) {

   string body = ConvertToJSON(request);  // You'll have to write your own JSON converter
   
   HttpRequest req("POST", m_send_addr, body);
   req.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
   req.AddHeader("Authorization", m_auth_header);
   
   HttpResponse resp;
   int errCode = req.Send(resp);
   if (errCode != 0) {
      return errCode;
   } else if (resp.StatusCode != 200) {
      return resp.StatusCode;
   } else {
      return 0;
   }
}
```

At the moment this is pretty bare-bones but it's open-source so feel free to modify and contribute.

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately, web requests are encrypted [for security reasons](https://www.mql5.com/en/forum/165425#comment_3969820), so the only way it to add them manually via the terminal or use a third-party dll to execute web requests.

Comment: I actually wrote my own web requests library to get around this issue.